# Synchronization and notify order of execution and scope

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

1) Does a thread relinquish it's lock as soon as notify is invoked within that threads synchronized code block, or once the synchronized code block is exited?

For instance, it seems like without specifying thread priority, my Process class will execute from top to bottom. Produce will be called first, it will do stuff, then wait(); consume will run, and then it hits notify(), which will print "Done" or will there be a 5 second delay first, then "Done" will be printed?

2) Also, if I had a third synchronized method/thread, that does not wait or notify and just runs, can I predict the order in which my operations are executed a priori?

3) Finally, how does notify() know what thread to 'wake up'? Like, let's say I have multiple Processes each executing 2 threads simultaneously, and each Process A, B, and C evoke notify( ).  Is each notify( ) local to each Process? In other words, if Process A calls notify( ), can that wake up a waiting thread in Process B? So far I've seen synchronized called on (this), which makes me think its referring to a particular object class, which in turn makes me think that all notify( )'s called in synchronized blocks are bound by whatever this in synchronized(this) is referring to, so there would be no cross-over.

```
public class Process {

public void produce( ) {
  synchronized(this) {
   // do stuff
    wait( );
     System.out.println("Done");
    }
}


public void consume( ) {
    synchronized(this) {
    // stuff
    notify(); 
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a simple program to test this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Process e = new Process();        
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                e.consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    e.produce();
}
```

This program waits 5000 milliseconds and prints

```
Done
```

As for your questions

> 1) Does a thread relinquish it's lock as soon as notify is invoked
>   within that threads synchronized code block, or once the synchronized
>   code block is exited?

The javadoc of `notify()` states

> If any threads are waiting on this object, **one of them is chosen to
>   be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of
>   the implementation.**strong text** A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling
>   one of the wait methods.
>
> **The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object**

So, no, the thread does not relinquish control of the lock when calling `notify()`. That will happen when code exits the `synchronized` block.

> 2) Also, if I had a third synchronized method/thread, that does not
>   wait or notify and just runs, can I predict the order in which my
>   operations are executed a priori?

You can estimate, but you can't be certain. Execution happens at the discretion of the Thread scheduler.

> 3) Finally, how does notify() know what thread to 'wake up'?

The call doesn't know. The Thread scheduler knows and chooses. You cannot control this.

The javadoc for `wait()` and `notify()` state

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of
>   this object's monitor.

and

> IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner
>   of this object's monitor.

So you can only call them on objects when you are inside a `synchronized` block that is synchronized on that object.

In your code example, the call

```
wait();
```

is implicitly doing

```
this.wait();
```

Comment: what if you call sleep for more than the thread's timeslice??.. the thread which is sleeping still keeps the monitor and the second thread waits for its entire timeslice waiting for the first thread to end its sleep?

Comment: @TheLostMind The thread relinquishes its timeslice when going to sleep. If the sleep is inside a `synchronized` block, the thread will still hold the monitor while it sleeps and the other thread will wait.

Comment: @TheLostMind The lock is held until the `synchronized` block exits. Period. Forget about timeslicing and all the other subtleties you're raising. Java doesn't even define timeslicing in the first place.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - What do you mean by relinquishes the timeslice?.. You mean to say that the moment sleep(x) is encountered, the scheduler doesnt even bother about scheduling this thread until "x" time elapses?.

Comment: @TheLostMind I mean the timeslice is revoked. You just told the thread scheduler you want to go to bed, so it will immediately schedule another thread.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - "So, no, the thread does not relinquish control of the lock when calling notify(). That will happen when code exits the synchronized block." .. You mean to say that if i have 1000 print statements in my synchronized block, then even if I call  notify() before my 1000 print statements, the other thread will not start executing ?. the other thread waits till all the 1000 print statements are executed ?

Comment: @TheLostMind Yes. Go ahead and try it with the code in the question and in my answer. Replace the `Thread.sleep` with a thousand Sysouts.

Comment: @TheLostMind Of course, but it's irrelevant. All you need to know is that the lock is held for the duration of the `synchronized` block. Timeslices only apply to executing threads, not to dormant ones.

Answer (score 3):

> Does a thread relinquish it's lock as soon as notify is invoked within that threads synchronized code block, or once the synchronized code block is exited?

When the 'synchronized' block exits. `notify()` doesn't itself affect the lock at all.

> will there be a 5 second delay first, then "Done" will be printed?

Yes.

> Also, if I had a third synchronized method/thread, that does not wait or notify and just runs, can I predict the order in which my operations are executed a priori?

You can't predict anything with threads. If you want a specific execution order you wouldn't use them.

> Finally, how does notify() know what thread to 'wake up'?

It doesn't. It 'wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation.'

> Like, let's say I have multiple Processes each executing 2 threads simultaneously, and each Process A, B, and C evoke notify( ). Is each notify( ) local to each Process?

`notify()` has nothing to do with your classes. It notifies an *object* and wakes up a *thread.*

> In other words, if Process A calls notify( ), can that wake up a waiting thread in Process B?

Yes.

> So far I've seen synchronized called on (this), which makes me think its referring to a particular object class

No. It refers to a particular *object.*

> which in turn makes me think that all notify( )'s called in synchronized blocks are bound by whatever this in synchronized(this) is referring to, so there would be no cross-over.

Don't think it. You've over-thinking this. `synchronized(x)` synchronizes on the object `x`, and `x.notify()` notifies it. Period.